# Dealing with in a finally block

Tags: java, exception, try-finally

I have some code which creates a `JarFile` and a `URLClassLoader`, both of which I want to close at the end. Naturally, I decided to use the `finally` block to deal with the cleanup:

```
JarFile jar = ...;
URLClassLoader loader = ...;
try {
    // work ...
} finally {
    jar.close();
    loader.close();
}
```

However, both `close()` invocations can throw an exception, so if `jar.close()` would throw an exception, then `loader.close()` would not be reached. One way I thought about working around this is by surrounding `jar.close()` with a try-catch block:

```
JarFile jar = ...;
URLClassLoader loader = ...;
try {
    // work ...
} finally {
    try {
        jar.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
    } 
    loader.close();
}
```

But this seems ugly and excessive. Is there an elegant way of dealing with cleanup-related exceptions in `finally` blocks?

Comment: Shouldn't you close items in the reversed order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java 7 and beyond, there is try with resources which handles `Closeable` objects.

Reformat your code thusly,

```
try(JarFile jar = ....; URLClassLoader loader = ....;) 
{
    // work ...
}
```

Only classes that implement the `Closeable` interface will work in this fashion, both of these classes meet this criteria.

Comment: Nice nice, I tend to miss those "new" features. Seems like I will refactor some code in an active project :)

Comment: Yeah, I really liked this feature, I always used a method `closeQuietly(Closeable... closeable)` to accomplish the same thing as Dici's answer, but allowed for a single call before.

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is a way to encapsulate this, it is called a method ! For example, you can create a class `IOUtils` as the following :

```
public class IOUtils {
    // this class is not meant to be instantiated
    private IOUtils() { }

    public static void closeQuietly(Closeable c) {      
       if (c == null) return;
       try {
          c.close();
       } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

And then,

```
JarFile jar = ...;
URLClassLoader loader = ...;
try {
    // work ...
} finally {
    closeQuietly(jar);
    loader.close();
}
```

As *Patrick J Abae II* told it, you can also use a try-catch with resources, but you can't always do that, for example if you first create an `InputStream` in a try-catch, and then create several different kinds of `InputStream` by encapsulating the first one (ex : encapsulate in a `CipherInputStream` to decipher the data and then write to a `FileOutputStream`). Yet, I'm not saying the try-catch with resources is not a useful construct, it is enough in most cases.

Comment: How do you probose this class shall be used?

Comment: @LutzHorn What do you mean ? It is meant to be use as any utilitly class, through static methods

Comment: Well, now that you have edited your answer it becomes clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
    try (JarFile jar = new JarFile(filename);
            URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls)) {
        // do stuff
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle ex           
    }
```